# Нужна помощь phpQuery::each

Tags: php, phpquery

Не могу понять принцип работы вышеуказанного метода phpQuery::each

Есть код:

```
$res = $forumPage->find('ul.topiclist dt .list-inner')->each(function ($dom) {  
    print_r(pq($dom)->find('.topictitle')->attr('href'));  
});
```

В результате выполнения `print_r()` на экран выводится то, что мне нужно.
если `print_r()` применить к `$res`, то обнаружится, что там лежит объект phpQuery, который среди прочего мусора содержит в себе то, что мне нужно(уже выводится).

Вопрос: что необходимо дописать, чтобы в результате выполнения вышеуказанного кода в какую-либо переменную-массив сохранялись куски, которые на данный момент успешно выводятся в результате `print_r(pq($dom)->find('.topictitle')->attr('href'));`

Comment: Я не сталкивался с `phpQuery`, но уверен, что `pq($dom)->find('.topictitle')` возвращает Вам массив элементов. Вам нужно взять нулевой. Возможно там есть метод типа `...->get(0)` или `...->first()`. Тогда у Вас в распоряжении будет нужный вам элемент, у которого можно забрать атрибут.

Comment: Согласен. Массив возвращается, атрибут выдернуть могу, но зациклился на методе `each()`.

Comment: Метод `each` просто перебирает каждый элемент и применяет для каждого элемента функцию, которая передается в качестве аргумента. В вашем случае - это анонимная функция, которая принимает `$dom` а потом делает `print_r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если прям решение "в лоб", то у вас ответ уже в самом вопросе – сохраняйте в массив. Что бы переменная была доступна в анонимной функции используйте `use` (см. [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php))

```
$result = [];
$forumPage->find('ul.topiclist dt .list-inner')->each(function($dom) use ($result) {  
    $result[] = pq($dom)->find('.topictitle')->attr('href');  
});
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: NULL, к сожалению